# EXPTIME and parallel computing

Tags: complexity-theory, parallel-computing

Can we solve an EXPTIME-complete problem  in polynomial time given 2^N processors?(N is the size of input).

Comment: "Does a DTM M hold after k steps on input x" is the canonical EXPTIME complete problem. I don't think general TM simulation profits from many processors, so I think the answer to your question is no.

Comment: in some cases yes, in some cases no, it depend on the internal "coupling" of the problem loosely related to how m,uch communication is reqd between processors. for ["embarrassingly parallel"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problems the answer is yes. there are some open theoretical questions in this area... efficient parallel algorithms is sometimes called the NC class...

Comment: I agree with vzn, it is possible. However, it depends on the complexity of the problem in hand. Not all solutions found using parallel algorithms are work optimal and if they aren't work optimal, its a waste.